Arduino環境でGNSS add-onボードを用いて同時に放送された複数のQZQSMを同時に出力したい
開発環境
Windows 11 Home 22H2
Arduino IDE 2.3.2
Spresense v3.2.0 (release 2024/2/9)
Spresense GNSS Add-onボード FW v00.144
やりたいこと
Arduino環境でGNSS add-onボードを用いて同時に放送された複数の災危通報を同時に出力したい．
QZSSでは4機のみちびきから災危通報を放送している．これら衛星それぞれからの受信データを出力したい．
試したこと
以下のプログラムで試行．
1秒に1回GPGGAセンテンスを出力し，災危通報は無限ループで常に出力を試みる．一回の平均ループ時間は0.007msであった．
void loop(){
  if (Gnss.isUpdate()){
    Gnss.getPositionData(&PositionData);
    NMEA_Output2(&PositionData.Data);
  }
  void *handle = Gnss.getDCReport();
  if(handle){
    NMEA_DcReport_Output2((struct cxd56_gnss_dcreport_data_s*)handle);
  }
}

災危通報は2秒に1回放送されているため2秒に1回(複数の衛星から受信した場合は複数個が連続して)の出力が想定されるが，以下のような結果を得た．
$GPGGA,101842.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,08,0.8,128.1,M,38.7,M,,*68
$QZQSM,56,9AB0440DE0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000380018B8*04
$GPGGA,101843.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,07,0.8,128.1,M,38.7,M,,*66
$QZQSM,56,53ADF4090F0002C3E8588ACB118162352C47E58FB4B1F91660E00010C001B7C*0F
$GPGGA,101844.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,08,0.8,128.1,M,38.7,M,,*6E
$GPGGA,101845.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,07,0.8,128.1,M,38.7,M,,*60
$GPGGA,101846.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,08,0.8,128.1,M,38.7,M,,*6C
$QZQSM,56,C6B2E40DE00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003C001530*75
$GPGGA,101847.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,07,0.8,128.1,M,38.7,M,,*62
$GPGGA,101848.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,08,0.8,128.1,M,38.7,M,,*62
$QZQSM,56,9AADF4090F0002D0045A710B4FD96A0050410A08340000000000001100013A8*08
$GPGGA,101849.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,07,0.8,128.1,M,38.7,M,,*6D
$GPGGA,101850.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,08,0.8,128.1,M,38.7,M,,*6A
$GPGGA,101851.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,07,0.8,128.1,M,38.7,M,,*64
$GPGGA,101852.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,08,0.8,128.1,M,38.7,M,,*68
$QZQSM,56,C6ADF4090F0002C3E8588ACB118162352C47E58FB4B1F91660E000114001030*0F
$GPGGA,101853.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,07,0.8,128.1,M,38.7,M,,*6E
$QZQSM,56,9AB0440DE000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001504*7C

想定通り2秒に1回出力されるときもあれば2秒連続で出力されることもある．
また，同一の衛星からのみしか受信していない．
Gnss.getDCReport();では/dev/gps2中から災危通報を取得し，災危通報の内容が更新されていれば返り値を出す．それ以外はNULLを返している．したがって，/dev/gps2中の災危通報をバッファする箇所が更新されていないことが想定される．
知りたいこと

試行プログラムのアルゴリズムに誤りがないか．
/dev/gps2の災危通報のバッファ箇所の更新頻度及び更新方法．ソースコードがあれば読むことができるためソースコードがあればよいです．
以前Spresense GNSS Add-onボードでは災危通報向けに2つのGNSSチャンネルを割り当てていると伺ったがgetDCReport()ではCXD56_GNSS_READ_OFFSET_DCREPORTでメモリ移動し災危通報を読み取っている．複数のチャンネルから受信した災危通報は1か所にバッファされているのかそれともCXD56_GNSS_READ_OFFSET_DCREPORT以外の場所が存在するのか．


現状の動作はどうなっていて、それをどうしたいんでしょうか。問題が見えません

みちびきが複数体制 なのは、「広範囲をカバーする」「位置情報をより正確にする」ためであり、災危通報に関しては (質問で求めている) "複数の衛星から取得" の必要性があまり見い出せません。それぞれ異なる情報を発信しているのでしょうか？

試行プログラムでは目的が達成できていない旨を追記し，想定出力の問題点を記載しました．不明点が多く申し訳ありません．
また，みちびきの災危通報は2機づつの組で異なるメッセージを放送しています．

Arduino環境では多くのコードがprebuiltライブラリ(ビルド済みバイナリ)になっているので、
ソースコードを読む場合は、Spresense SDKを参照する必要があります。
以前に似たようなことを調べたことがあるのですが、SDK側のコードで、
spresense/nuttx/boards/arm/cxd56xx/drivers/sensors/cxd5610_gnss.c#L782-L797
cxd5610_gnss_notify_dcreport()関数で、災危通報のバッファは1個に制限しているようです。
ただ、NMEAの$GQGSVセンテンスの出力をみたときに、
QZSS L1Sの可視衛星が1機のみしか見えていないことが多いので、
ソースコードを変更したとしても複数衛星からの災危通報受信は難しいのではないかと思います。
